# Mathematical Context of MPT formula in qiskit VQE

Tags: qiskit, vqe

In the video at timestamp: 43:34, We input the mean-variance parameters.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtMVoGXlz04&t=3327s

Based on the formula as mentioned here in section Formulation
https://github.com/qiskit-community/ibm-quantum-challenge-fall-2021/blob/main/content/challenge-1/challenge-1.ipynb

q=0.7
Mu = 2.5 , 4.2, 1
how does one mathematically calculate the result that is arrived using VQE algorithm?